# Store Data locally only Using Parse

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

Can I store Data locally only (never want to save it on server) using Parse local database? 
The reason we want to use parse to do this is that the same code(logic) can be easily used in IOS, Android and other places.
Thanks

Comment: what I want is that some of the data will be stored locally by Parse and will never save it to their server.  calling [[PFUser currentUser] saveEventually] will save everything to their server which kind of sucks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with parse, but if it has a local database then you certainly should be able to.

Alternatively, save it to file:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

save it an SQLite database ( I recommend using sugar, it makes it trivial).

https://satyan.github.io/sugar/

or if you only need it for the time the app is open, Use a Bundle.

Comment: what I want is that some of the data will be stored locally by Parse and will never save it to their server.  calling [[PFUser currentUser] saveEventually] will save everything to their server which kind of sucks

Comment: Yep so look at my other options. Neither of them will upload anything.

Comment: I believe the answer isn't related to the question, as the user asked for Parse solution.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you keep your ParseObjects pinned, you can use them offline indefinitely.

See Parse's release announcements for the Local Datastore. Links to the guide and API are located at the bottom of the respective page: [Android](http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/) | [iOS](http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use only `pinInBackground`. it will save only locally to the parse.